# Sci Fi Special Ops Team

Tags: story-identification

In 1972-73, I read a science fiction story about a special operations team. One member had super strength, one was a gymnast-acrobat, one was an expert marksman, & one a human computer. Their mission was on a planet modeled after Spain under the Franco regime. The story was part of an anthology.

Anyone remember it?

Comment: This sounds like a story that I read by Mack Reynolds. The gymnast was a girl/small woman. The chef was an expert with throwing knives. I can not remember the title.

Comment: I checked Mack Reynolds' list of stories on Wikipedia. "Fiesta Brava" would appear to be it. It was an anthology published in 1970.

Comment: @HaroldF, I'm going to go ahead and post this as an answer, but if you ever come back... or RobertLowry for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

As confirmed above by the querent in the comments:

> I checked Mack Reynolds' list of stories on Wikipedia. "[Fiesta Brava](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45562)" would appear to be it. It was an anthology published in 1970. – *Harold F Jun 28 '13 at 22:49*